# Manually Application Vs Jmeter reports differences

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

I have recorded the script and run test with 1vuser.Checked the response of the application by using developer tools and the response got in application side and response from the jmeter is same but manually open the Application in the broswer the response getting is after 60seconds but while running the script with 1Vusers, Think Time 5 to 7 seconds and pacing time 5 to 7 seconds getting the response time is 2.400seconds.

Getting same response in application developer tools and jmeter response but while manually accessing in browser response is taking 60 seconds.

How should I explain this to my client.

Could anyone please help me  [image]
[image]

Comment: This question and the linked ones are by the same OP. OP, please don't open multiple questions for the same problem. You can edit your original if you need to change it or add more info!

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved JMeter test should produce the same network footprint as the real browser.

So make sure that your [JMeter is configured to behave exactly like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in terms of:

1. Handling embedded resources and [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
2. Handling [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests
3. Handling [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) and other [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
4. Handling [think times](https://q-automations.com/jmeter-think-time/)

If you compare end-to-end scenario in browser containing 7 requests with JMeter wrap everything into a [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) and configure it to generate the parent sample and include duration of timers into generated sampler.